# Walking or running makes me consume 200 to 550 kcal/h, that's true, but always 68 to 72 kcal per kilometer whatever the effort done. Why?

Tags: metabolism

My connected watch tells me that when :

- I'm walking I'm consuming 200 - 250 kcal per hour,
- running: from 500 to 550.

and this is ok.

But it also tells me, that how many kilometers are my trips, I'm consuming 70 kcal (68 to 72) for each kilometer, whatever I am going cool slowly (at 4.5 km/h) or running 10 kilometers (at 9 km/h).

It's not what I would have guessed.

In my mind, my body should spend more calories during a distance where it is doing more exercise than when it doesn't.

It's possible that I'm doing a logic mistake, but I'm missing something here, and I'm intrigued.

Comment: Connected devices aren't perfect, no matter how "smart" they're advertised to be. To actually determine the amount of energy you're using requires an awful lot of specialized equipment.

Comment: In addition to Matt's comment, are you considering resting metabolism? All the "background" stuff: keeping your brain on, your digestive system going, running your kidneys, synthesizing replacement proteins in all your tissues. If you include that in your calories per distance, there's going to be more background per distance when you move slower. If you sit still, your calories per distance are going to become infinite.